# Error with Sepolia Faucet - ReCAPTCHA not Recognized Despite Correct Completion

Tags: blockchain, testnets, alchemy, sepolia

I am facing an issue while using the Sepolia Faucet provided by Alchemy through [sepoliafaucet.com](https://sepoliafaucet.com). Every time I try to access the faucet and complete the ReCAPTCHA, I encounter the error message,

> "Your request did not complete the reCAPTCHA as expected, so we could
> not complete your request. Please refresh the page and try again."

The problem is that I have correctly completed the ReCAPTCHA multiple times, but the faucet still won't process my request.

Has anyone else encountered this issue while using the Sepolia Faucet? Is there a known solution or workaround to resolve this problem? I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance to successfully access the faucet and claim the tokens.

Comment: Have you logged in to your Alchemy account?
What browser are you using?

Comment: Chainstack also offers a faucet now; try it out if needed! https://faucet.chainstack.com/sepolia-faucet

Comment: @ChefAharoni Yes, I am logged in to my Alchemy account from chrome browser.